# Error Connecting Database: Using Environment Variables into wp-config.php

Tags: php, wordpress, environment-variables

I want to configure a wordpress site for which my wp-config should take database values from Environment variables. I have set my environment variables but during it shows "Error establishing a database connection".

here is the code i am using

```
define('DB_NAME', getenv('DB'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('us'));
define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('pa'));
define('DB_HOST', getenv('end'));
```

I have tried it running from terminal as well but error is same. I am not able to figure out what is causing this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Database Error</title>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Error establishing a database connection</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is their something being missed??

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining same `DB_NAME` constant for database user name, password and host change the constants

Try like this

```
define('DB_NAME', getenv('DB'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('us'));
define('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('pa'));
define('DB_HOST', getenv('end'));
```

Comment: Are you sure the environment variables have the correct value?

Comment: yes, I have tried connecting using the values instead of env variables and it works. But running with Env variables it give connection error.

Comment: sure that the env variables are set? try to echo them and check

Comment: In that case it should work, this error shows only when the connection strings are wrong please double check you have all the info correct

Comment: Getting this error now - has anyone diagnosed this ghost issue?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can create .htaccess file where you will say
SetEnv DB Abc;
and in php echo DB;

Comment: did you create .htaccess?

Comment: While this is a working option, it will have it's side effects, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267713/allow-cpanel-to-manage-setenv-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving the same error. It looked like my `wp-config.php` was being called twice from two different locations. The way I was referencing my `.env` file was incorrect.

If you're doing anything similar to this in your `wp-config.php`:

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
if(file_exists(".env")) {
    $dotenv->load();
}
```

The **correct way** is by referencing the right path before the file. Like so:

```
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . '.env')) {
    $dotenv->load();
}
```

This ended up solving my problem when I called environment variables like so:

```
define( 'DB_HOST', getenv('DB_HOST') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set variables using the `php.ini` file. In some shared hostings (like [uberspace](https://manual.uberspace.de/lang-php/#etc-php-d)) you have a special `php.d` folder with custom ini files.

This is how your `wordpress.ini` file could look like:

```
WP_DB_NAME=example
...
```

And this is how you can access it in `wp-config.php`:

```php
...
define( 'DB_NAME', get_cfg_var('WP_DB_NAME') );
...
```

Make sure to reload the php config. This is somewhat special to your provider, I could also imagine that they reload it every 5 minutes or so. On uberspace you can do it with:

```
uberspace tools restart php
```

Sadly not all hosting providers give you that much freedom. However this was a nice way for me to place the configuration somewhere outside the folder where all my wordpress files are. Then I can safely backup them without exposing the database password in the backup.