# Allow cPanel to manage SetEnv parameters

Tags: apache, cpanel

We have a application that makes use of an Apache environment parameter to determine what config it should use. Around 5 instances of the application are is hosted on one cPanel / WHM development server.

We could use the `.htaccess` to set the right environment, but that results in uncommitted changes. cPanel should handle this variable via the vhost file, basically each vhost should have a different value:

```
SetEnv APP_ENV dev
SetEnv APP_ENV test
SetEnv APP_ENV trans
```

So, how can we let cPanel handle environment variables? It doesn't seem that this is possible, given the `SetEnv` can't be found in the vhost template.

https://blog.rac.me.uk/2013/05/29/new-relic-cpanel-apache-and-fastcgi-php/

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with custom php.ini file (most of the hosting provider give option to create custom php.ini file, create custome php.ini file for each domain  )

Add configuration in custom php.ini file

```
APP_ENV="dev"
```

form php code we can use [get_cfg_var()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-cfg-var.php) function to retrieve

```
<?php
echo "current env is   : ".get_cfg_var('APP_ENV');
?>
```

Output

[image: Output]